# Convert QList<std::string> to QList<QString>

Tags: c++, qt

Is there an easy way to create a `QList<QString>` from `QList<std::string>`?

(Without iterating `QList<std::string>` and adding each element to `QList<QString>`)

Comment: The only way will be to create a new QList and iterate over it. You could probably use some generic algorithms in the STL to do so.

Comment: Why do you not want to iterate?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO. How could you possibly convert one into another without iterating? Even if you are using some kind of functions, that will be iterating through the list.

Comment: "without iterating?" - probably means `std::transform`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without iterating through your list. You can still do it efficiently, avoiding unnecessary copies and reallocations:

```
QList<std::string> listStd;
listStd << "one" << "two" << "three";

QList<QString> listQt;
listQt.reserve(listStd.length());
for(const std::string& s : listStd)
{
    listQt.append(QString::fromStdString(s));
}

// listQt: "one", "two", "three"
```

If you don't want to convert, you may want to save your `std::string` directly as `QString`, thus avoiding the need to convert later.

```
QList<QString> lst; // or you can use the typedef QStringList 
....
std::string s = getting_a_std_string_from_this_function();
lst.append(QString::fromStdString(s));
```